# PHP - Fill in select boxes with value form database

Tags: php, forms, loops, dom

I've a form with select boxes and a value from database which has been chosen before. Yes I need this value which is chosen to be shown as last chosen inside form. I try using php dom but I' m not getting anywhere.

So here is the html:

```
<select name="conf_1">
     <option value="Y">Yes</option>
     <option value="N">No</option>
</select>
<select name="conf_2">
     <option value="text">text</option>
     <option value="alsotext">alsotext</option>
</select>
```

And now I would like to show the chosen option which is stored in array like this:

```
$confs = array([1] => N, [2] => text );
```

Do some code:

```
loop{
   <option value="$confs[$i]">$confs[$i]</option> has to be appended to <select name="conf_$i">
}
```

Now I can't find a way to do this. I've tried using php dom but I don't know how to select element by name attribute and then loop trough so I can't make a real php example. I just would not know where to start.

If someone just has a way to do this please enlighten me!?

Done it with this code inspired by @Markus I.:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($form);
    $xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('select') as $select) {
        $name = $select->getAttribute('name');
        $name = str_replace('conf_', '', $name);

        foreach($xPath->query('./option', $select) as $option) {
            if ($option->getAttribute('value') == $confs[$name]) {
                $option->setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
            }
        }
    }

    $form = $dom->saveHTML($dom);

    echo $form;
```

Comment: alternatively you can do it through javascript

Comment: If you already have the values, a simple loop would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to load the hole template into a DOM and modify it: (Code not tested!)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('<yourTemplateXML />');
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$data = array('conf1' => 'N', 'conf2' => 'text');


foreach ($xPath->query('//select') as $select) {
    foreach($xPath->query('./option', $select) as $option) {
        if ($option->getAttribute('value') == $data[$select->getAttribute('name')]) {
            $option->setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
        }
    }
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

I wrote a class, which can handle all field-types. Note this is only samplecode. On production you should take care if the key in your data-array exists and so on.

This has a nice Side-effect: Because you set the Value via dom, it protects your form from XSS

Comment: humm this looks like it but I get this error - Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::query() in C:\usb webserver\root\tcm\engine.php on line 372, ok I fixed it I use getElementsByTagName to loop trough all the select elements and then I use your xPath method to deal with selected

Comment: Sorry, don't tested the code... :)

To getElementsByTagName is anyway better in this situation, because it's faster; xPath is overkill...

Comment: Don't worry you sowed the right direction I can press on form here. thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Like this ??

```
$confs_arr = array("1" => N, "2" => text,"3" => N4, "4" => text3,"5" => N5,"6" => text7);
echo "<select name='option' id='option'>";
foreach($confs_arr as $keys=>$confs){

echo "<option value='".$confs."'>".$confs."</option>";

}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: No you see the form is not made manually its already there so I have $form and then I have to manipulate it so the select values witch are stored in array will be filed in. This is because the form is dynamic and there is a form generator witch can make new forms with new values.

Comment: @sirwilliam so if you are getting all values in array,above code will work. you just have to pass the values

Comment: That is the problem they have to be inserted in an existing form witch is stored in db loaded into string. Every time the form is diffident and has diffident values attached to it. But I already fixed it with help of @Markus I.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code similar to the one you asked:

```
   <?php

$categories = $rows; //array from database
foreach($rows as $row){
     if($row['name'] == $_POST['category']){
          $isSelected = ' selected="selected"'; // if the option submited in form is as same as this row we add the selected tag
     } else {
          $isSelected = ''; // else we remove any tag
     }
     echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'".$isSelected.">".$row['name']."</option>";
}
?>
```

`$_POST['category']` is user previously selected, it can be anything, not just `$_POST`.

Based on this example, you can modify your code.

If user previously chose `"text"`, then the html code should be :

```
<select name="conf_2">
     <option value="text" selected="selected">text</option>
     <option value="alsotext">alsotext</option>
</select>
```

Put `selected="selected"` in the `<option>` tag and this item will be chosen as default.

Hope this helps